# spring security's .formLogin method is not work

Tags: spring, spring-security

when I start server and access my localhost:8080,
then comeout springSecurity's base login page.
I use loginPage() and defaultSuccessUrl() but didnt work.

and my Java version is 20.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain fillterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       return http.csrf().disable()
               .authorizeHttpRequests()
               .requestMatchers("/members/**").authenticated()
               .requestMatchers("/").authenticated()
               .anyRequest().permitAll()
               .and()
               .formLogin()
               .loginPage("/members/login")
               .loginProcessingUrl("/loginProc")
               .defaultSuccessUrl("/mainpage",true)
               .and().build();
    }
}
```

I also add spring security depandancy in properties file.